# viewPager within dynamic Fragment, wrong state position

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, sharedpreferences, fragmentstatepageradapter, android-actionbaractivity

before, thanks lot for take time for my questions !

I have a BIG problem in my project,
I used `viewPager` within dynamic `Fragment`

> 6 fragments used

so i `extend FragmentStatePagerAdapter()` for in my `Activity`.
i want to swipe automatically from state 0 to 1 and to 5
in `getItem()` i create my tabs (i loaded 4 or 5 tab from 6)
log in my `onCreateView()`

> tab 0,
>   tab 1,
>   tab 2,
>   tab 3,
>   tab 4,
>   tab 5

log in autoplay `preference context`

> tab 0 auto,
>   tab 1 auto,
>   tab 2 auto,
>   tab 3 auto,
>   tab 4 auto,
>   tab 5 auto,

in log below, i have wrong with my code
`viewPager` at the first time 2 page loaded and i want to load just 1 fragment

[see my Log screen capture](http://s4.picofile.com/file/8172879834/log.png)

the true log (for 5 dynamic tabs) must be :

> tab 0 (first load and then) tab 0 auto , tab 1 (second load and then) tab 1 auto , tab 3 (third load and then) tab 3 auto , tab 4 (fourth load and then) tab 4 auto , tab 5 (fifth load and then) tab 5 auto

I know that who `ViewPager` by default will load 3 `fragments` into memory,

I have try some sol like [this](http://semycolon.blogspot.in/2014/12/refresh-pageviewer-fragment-everytime.html) but I don`t got any sol for me.

how to fix my viewpager and fragment position id to get just current status ?

please help me! 
tnx again dude.

Comment: I used this method `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` and 98% fixed it, but i stay in 1 problem ! [see new Log](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8172930034/log2.png) : **tab 4** is loded at the first time in stack, but **tab 2 auto** and **tab 3 auto**, not going to **tab 4** and SKIPPED ! what wrong ?

Comment: Please add your code into your question.